# send mail attachment powershell

Tags: powershell, email, smtp

I'm working on a project(bonus points) for my intro CyberSec class and I have a cmd script to create a file with info in a usb drive i was trying to use powershell to send the email to myself but keep getting this error:

```
At D:\mail.ps1:6 char:16
+ $att= $USBDRIVE\file.zip
+                ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\file.zip' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

here is my powershell script in the entirety.

```
$USBDRIVE= Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.label -eq 'ARNOLDHMW' } | 
select -expand driveletter

Compress-Archive -Path $USBDRIVE\file -DestinationPath $USBDRIVE\file.zip

$email = "*"

$pass = "*"

$att= $USBDRIVE\file.zip

$smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.EnableSSl = $true
$msg.From = "$email"
$msg.To.Add("$email")
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$msg.Subject = "Files Captured"
$msg.Body = "
</br>
Hi there
"
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$email", 
"$pass");
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

email and password blanked out for obvious reasons
i'm at a loss here. thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post errors as pictures, but text instead. We want to copy&paste stuff!

Comment: Okay sorry about that.

Comment: On the subject of quoting strings, I'd recommend reading [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) as this is likely an issue you'll to hit when learning powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue you are having is because the value you pass to assign `$att` isn't a string value. Try assigning the variable as a string instead

```
$att = "$USBDrive\File.zip"
```

or better yet

```
$att = Join-Path -Path $USBDrive -ChildPath "file.zip"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Its always the small syntax that gets me!